# Does QElapsedTimer actually create a timer?

Tags: qt, timer, qt5

`QTimer` seems to actually create a "timer" that consumes CPU ticks and posts events etc. Is the same true for `QElapsedTimer`?

Or is this just something like win32's `GetTickCount` where by when you call a method on `QElapsedTimer` it grabs the current tick count and subtracts from the count where it was started?

I want to know if its a good idea to have these things hanging around, or will they eat battery like `QTimer`?

Comment: You'd get the best answer by reading the source code.

Comment: `create a "timer" that consumes CPU ticks` *What?* It doesn't "consume" anything.

Comment: Note that QTimer is for _triggering_ timed events. QElapsedTimer is for _measuring_ time. They have completely different purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QTimer` will "eat" battery only in some cases. Specifically, if it is a `Qt::PreciseTimer` on Windows 7 and earlier - on those systems, it will ramp up the tick frequency to 1000Hz. Very short timers will force the same behavior. Since those systems are *not* tickless, the presence of an active coarse timer does nothing to power consumption, since the system ticks at a fixed rate whether it needs to or not.

On a tickless operating system, `QTimer` does not have such ill effects. This includes OS X/xnu, Windows 8 or tickless Linux.

`QElapsedTimer` is not a `QObject` and does not provide any asynchronous events. It simply provides an interface to the platform's time APIs (*not* timer APIs).